# No content provider for remote video in android?

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, android-videoview

I am learning android. I am recording short videos and uploading to aws server. After uploading I am getting the preSigned Url of video that is looking like follow:

```
https://bluetape-rakesh.s3.amazonaws.com/2/32042416717093rangeela.mp4-540x960_rang.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AK4VVEOWZPUIIRZ2&Expires=1665775032&Signature=gKwCXgY48%2BdY3ba9lVCe%2BhI%3D
```

To play the video in videoView in android , I am using following code in android .

```
Uri videoURI = Uri.parse(Video_url);
videoView.setVideoURI(videoURI);
```

But I am getting an error in android studio of:

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://bluetape-rakesh.s3.amazonaws.com/2/32042416717093rangeela.mp4-540x960_rang.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIARV4VVEOWZPUIIRZ2&Expires=1665775032&Signature=gKwCXgY48%2BdY3ba9kDA6lVCe%2BhI%3D
```

What is wrong with me? Please help. How to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be a content scheme uri. Such an uri starts with content://. Yours starts with https:// protocol. It means that the error you get in your Android app (not in Android Studio) that the video player will not download the file. You have to download it first. Or take another player.

Comment: @blackapps: `VideoView`, like `MediaPlayer`, works with `https` URLs. It is not limited to `content` `Uri` values.

Comment: @Rakesh: Have you requested the `INTERNET` permission in your manifest?

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I have already provided INTERNET permission in Manifiest file.